# Woocommerce programmed order does not trigger confirmation email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, methods, orders

I create a woordpress plugin that generates a code, links it to a downloadable virtual product. I use this code, once validated to create a woocommerce order in php. When I change the order status the email is never sent to the customer. However, on the production site, customers receive confirmation emails correctly. (The plugin is not on the production site).

I tried to do the status change with :
`$order->set_status('completed')`
`$order->update_status('completed')`
I've tried to do it manually in the commands dashboard, but it doesn't change anything.

What I'd like is for the plugin to create a woocommerce order with the customer's email address when the code is validated. (the customer doesn't have to have an account to order) The order goes directly to Shipping, and the download email is sent. The customer opens the e-mail and downloads the file. I don't understand what the problem is, if someone has already come across this problem or if someone has an idea I'd love to hear from you.

I'll share my code with you:

```
function ode_cd_traitment_download_code_form()
{
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['code']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $code = sanitize_text_field($_POST['code']);
    $email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']);
    $remaining_uses = remaining_uses($code);
    $validation_result = ode_cd_validate_data_download_form($code, $email, $remaining_uses);

    if (!empty($validation_result)) {
      return $validation_result;
    } else {
      if (ode_cd_code_exists_in_database($code)) {
        decrement_uses($code);
        $new_remaining_uses = remaining_uses(($code));

        ode_cd_create_order($code, $email);

        wp_redirect(home_url("/test-page/?success=true&remaining_uses=$new_remaining_uses"));
        exit;
      } else {
        return "Le code renseigner est inconnue de notre service.";
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action('init', 'ode_cd_traitment_download_code_form');

function ode_cd_create_order($code, $email)
{

  $product_id = get_product_id_by_unique_code($code);

  $order = wc_create_order();
  $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
  $order->add_product($product, 1);
  $order->set_billing_email($email);
  //$order->set_status('completed');
  $order->save();
  // $order->update_status('completed');
  //$order->save();
}
```

Have a nice day and thanks in advance to those who reply.

Comment: You Are posting partial code. Post your full code

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `woocommerce_init` hook instead of WordPress `init` hook.

Try the following function replacement code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'ode_cd_traitment_download_code_form');
function ode_cd_traitment_download_code_form()
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['code']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $code = sanitize_text_field($_POST['code']);
        $email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']);
        $remaining_uses = remaining_uses($code);
        $validation_result = ode_cd_validate_data_download_form($code, $email, $remaining_uses);

        if (!empty($validation_result)) {
            return $validation_result;
        } else {
            if (ode_cd_code_exists_in_database($code)) {
                decrement_uses($code);
                $new_remaining_uses = remaining_uses(($code));

                if( ode_cd_create_order($code, $email) ) {
                    wp_redirect(home_url("/test-page/?success=true&remaining_uses=$new_remaining_uses"));
                    exit;
                } else {
                    return "Un problème est survenu lors de la creation de la commande.";
                }
            } else {
                return "Le code renseigné est inconnu de notre service.";
            }
        }
    }
}

function ode_cd_create_order( $code, $email ){
    $product_id = get_product_id_by_unique_code($code);

    if ( ! $code || ! ($product_id > 0) || ! is_email($email) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $order = wc_create_order();
    $order->set_customer_user_agent( wc_get_user_agent() );
    $order->add_product(wc_get_product($product_id), 1);
    $order->set_billing_email($email);
    $order->set_status('completed');

    // Calculate totals, save order data to the database and returns the order total amount
    return $order->calculate_totals(); 
}
```

It should work.

I have tested the code inside `ode_cd_create_order()` function with a real email and a valid product ID:

- An order is created with completed status
- Email notifications are sent:

  - to the admin (new order email)
  - to the costumer (order completed email)